# restarting a (audio) loop after it has finished

Tags: iphone, loops, audio

I want to play an audio loop by turning on a switch but i do not want the loop to end until the switch is turned off. When the loop ends i want it to simply start back at the beginning as to be continuos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. Note the `-1` tells the music to repeat indefinitely:

Import this file at the top of your file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Then to use it:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resourcePath ofType:@"caf"];

NSError *activationError = nil;
NSError *audioPlayerInitError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error:&activationError];

NSURL *newURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:newURL error:&audioPlayerInitError];

[newPlayer prepareToPlay];
[newPlayer setVolume:.8];
[newPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1]; // -1 means play indefintely
[newPlayer setDelegate: self];
[newPlayer play];
[newPlayer release];
```

And then to stop it you would do:

```
if ([newPlayer isPlaying]) {
    [newPlayer stop];
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain AVAudioPlayer. I understand its a class reference but my code is telling me that its undeclared. As well as AVAudioSession.

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to tell you to import the AVFoundation header. I've edited my answer.